# Unusual byte sequence to set R8 to 128

Tags: assembly, x86-64

In a piece of system code (in Delphi), I found this sequence ($ means "hex"):

```
    DB      $49,$C7,$C0,$80,$00,$00,$00  // MOV  R8, 128
```

And indeed, it sets R8 to 128 in the debugger. But wouldn't:

```
    MOV     R8D,$80 // or $00000080
```

do the same? Is there something special about the former byte sequence (speed, setting some flags, whatever) that could have made the author of the code prefer it over the way using R8D?

---

On request, a little more of the code:

```
// RAX/XMM : 16BYTES VALUE. RDX: COUNT. RCX: DEST. ADDRESS. (16BTYES ALIGNED)
@@COPY128:
        DB    $49,$C7,$C0,$80,$00,$00,$00  // MOV  R8, 128
        CMP   RDX,R8
        JL    @@COPY64
        SUB   RDX,R8
        DB    $0F,$1F,$80,$00,$00,$00,$00 // NOP DWORD PTR [EAX + 00000000H] ; NOP(7)
@@COPY128LOOP:
        MOVDQA [RCX      ],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $10],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $20],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $30],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $40],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $50],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $60],XMM0
        MOVDQA [RCX + $70],XMM0
        ADD   RCX,R8
        SUB   RDX,R8
        JG    @@COPY128LOOP
        ADD   RDX,R8

@@COPY64:
```

This is part of a routine called `_FillChar`,  which fills a piece of memory with multiples of a single byte (or char), more or less like `memset()` in other languages.

Comment: Are there any "cheats", such as using the bytes for an other purpose than executing them or self-modifying code, or special concerns such as alignment?

Comment: @harold: I don't know. The entire code is (manually) aligned, but that is simply done with NOPs (or multi-byte equivalents) which are not executed anyway. The value 128 is required, and used as a loop counter.

Comment: There is no normal reason to prefer the 64bit encoding, it just wastes a byte (but that may be used for alignment purposes)

Comment: They don't do the same thing, the former sign-extends the operand, the latter doesn't.  We can't tell what affected the exact operand value, surely you could show more code, but it was probably just easier to rely on sign-extension.  x64 is highly partial to addressing memory with signed 32-bit offsets, in practice it is a segmented architecture.

Comment: @HansPassant the sign is zero though

Comment: @harold: Given that the target register is `r8` I don't see how you could possibly avoid the `rex` prefix.

Comment: @EOF you can't, but by writing to `r8d` you can use the `b8` encoding: `41 b8 80 00 00 00` (for a 64bit target it would have an imm64, so the `c7` encoding wins)

Comment: I don't have it here, but I will post a little more code later on.

Comment: It looks like it may be hand-written assembly code for something like `memset`, so perhaps the implementer simply didn't use the most efficient encoding. On other hand, the presence of the 7-byte `nop` directly before the top of the loop is interesting since it seems like it doesn't align to an interesting boundary if the initial function is really 16-byte aligned as you indicate.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yes, it is hand-written assembly, but the `@@COPY128LOOP' is properly aligned to a 16 byte boundary (I only posted a snippet, the entire routine is pretty long). So it was probably chosen because it uses 7 bytes instead of 6? That would not surprise me. The Delphi built-in assembler does not have a directive to align the next piece of code to a certain boundary (not yet, at least), so it must be done manually.

Comment: Perhaps it was just unintentional use of the instruction that uses an extra byte (although in this case you mostly get it back by shortening the following `nop`), or perhaps the author wanted to shorten the `nop` above the loop for some reason.

Comment: If that were the case why not just use an 8 byte multibyte nop like `NOP DWORD ptr [EAX + EAX*1 + 0x00000000]`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I don't know. I do know that the label is aligned, manually. And exactly what you say is what I wondered about too. Hence my question. I wondered if it did something I didn't know about.

Comment: Personally, I have a feeling that whoever hand coded it didn't know any better lol

Comment: @MichaelPetch: it would not really surprise me. Although the people who usually write such code (people of the FastCode project for Delphi) are pretty clever guys, using all the tricks in the books. They already considerably sped up a lot of routines in the Delphi runtime library.